# Stream GSM codec audio from network to speakers on the fly

Tags: python, audio, codec

i doing a VoIP software in python, i try to recreate a specific ham radio program protocol, it uses GSM audio codec.
as python has no easy way to play gsm files, i however managed to at least convert a file with it, so i know it is possible.

i use myfile.write(data3) from network stream to write a .gsm file on hard drive.
then i use pysoundfile to convert it to wav file

```
data, samplerate = sf.read('temppi.gsm')
sf.write('temppi.wav', data, samplerate)
```

after i can play it with pyaudio. it give huge delay it need to be on the fly not after audio packet came in..

My question how i can direcly on the fly play the file from stream with soundfile? i tried to search google all is only about converting files, there is no way to play it direcly on the fly? any suggestions what i could do. Thanks and happy new year :)

EDIT:
now i have it on fly but this is bad.. and it doing alot chunking sounds

```
here we start thread aaniulos

if ekabitti == b'\x01':
dataaa = self.socket.recv(198)
data3 = io.BytesIO(bytes(dataaa))

    while True:
        global aani
        #global data3
        if aani:
            print ('Ääni saije lopetetaan..')
            break
        data, samplerate = sf.read(io.BytesIO(bytes(data3.getbuffer())), format = 'RAW', channels = 1, samplerate=8000, dtype ='int16', subtype='GSM610', endian ='FILE')
        virtuaalifilu = io.BytesIO()
        sf.write (virtuaalifilu, data, 8000, format='wav', subtype= 'PCM_16')
        sound_file = io.BytesIO(bytes(virtuaalifilu.getbuffer()))
        print ('striimataan ääntä nyt kaijuttimiin!!!')

    stream.stop_stream()  
    stream.close()
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you omit much detail I can only guess how your implementation works. It sounds like you are not doing it correctly. My guess is that the huge delay you experience is because you are sending too much audio in each packet, maybe even a whole audio file? To achieve audio streaming with low latency you basically need to follow this crude scheme:

At the sender:

1. Record audio to a buffer.
2. Continuously slice the buffer in chunks of a pre-defined length, e.g. 20 milliseconds.
3. Encode each chunk with a suitable audio codec, e.g. GSM.
4. Send each chunk in a packet to the receiver, preferably using a datagram based protocol like UDP.

At the receiver:

1. Read packets from network when available.
2. Decode each packet to raw audio data and put it in an audio buffer.
3. Continuously play audio from the audio buffer.

If using UDP as transfer protocol you also need to handle packet losses and out-of-order packets. Depending on the latency requirements you could probably also use (or at least try) TCP to send each audio chunk.

To achieve continuous audio recording and playback [`sounddevice`](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io) seems to be a good alternative. For recording, check out `InputStream` or `RawInputStream`. For playback, have a look at `OutputStream` or `RawOutputStream`.

It might be possible to still use `SoundFile` to convert from GSM codec to raw audio, but you need to do that for each chunk. And the chunk must be quite small, e.g. 20 milliseconds.

Comment: letme be more specific:
data3 = self.socket.recv(198) <-- im reading 198 chuncks from network gsm audio data and write that direcly to the file.

Comment: How many samples are contained in these 183 bytes? And what is the samplerate? This will correspond to the delay or latency. Can you play the different audio chunks in a continuous and gapless way?

Comment: samplerate is 8000, i have no idea about audio chunks, audio plays fine whenever middle etc of stream, it is TCP stream.
i have updated my question by putting all code there how i do it now, i used bytesio but it is bad still, i can do it on the fly.